# Write into a word file using JAVA

Tags: java, apache-poi

I read a word document and want to write into another word file using Java. I want the style (font, bold, italic, heading, etc.) of the content in the read document to be written as it is the new document created.
I am able to copy the content but not the format style.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import java.util.List;

public class ReadFile 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception 
    {

        XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(new  FileInputStream("d:\\Profiles\\mehjain\\Desktop\\Test1.docx"));
        List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphList =  docx.getParagraphs();

        XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument(); 
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("d:\\Profiles\\mehjain\\Desktop\\Test2.docx"));
        XWPFParagraph n = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run=n.createRun();

        for (XWPFParagraph paragraph: paragraphList)
        { 
            run.setText(paragraph.getText());              
            run.addCarriageReturn();
        }
        document.write(out); 
        document.close();   
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Test2.docx written successfully");
    }
}
```

I got an answer to copy the same format of text but I am unable to copy numbers.
I executed this code:

```
 import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.IBody;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.model.StyleDescription;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFStyles;
import java.util.List;

public class ReadFile 
{
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception 
{

  XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(new    FileInputStream("d:\\Profiles\\mehjain\\Desktop\\Test1.docx"));

  List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphList =  docx.getParagraphs();

   XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument(); 
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("d:\\Profiles\\mehjain\\Desktop\\Test2.docx"));
   XWPFParagraph n = document.createParagraph();



  for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : paragraphList)
  {

       for(XWPFRun run1 : paragraph.getRuns())
       {
         XWPFRun run=n.createRun();
         run.setText(run1.getText(0));
        run.setFontFamily( run1.getFontFamily() );
        run.setBold( run1.isBold() );
        run.setItalic( run1.isItalic() );
        run.setStrike( run1.isStrike() );
        run.setColor( run1.getColor() );
        }
       XWPFRun run=n.createRun();
       run.addCarriageReturn();
    }
   document.write(out); 
   document.close();   
   out.close();
   System.out.println("Test2.docx written successfully"); 
  }
  }
```

Comment: Would copying whole paragraphs from Test1.docx to Test2.docx be an option? This would be possible using the method `setParagraph(XWPFParagraph paragraph, int pos)` of `XWPFDocument`.

Comment: What do you mean with "I am unable to copy numbers"? Do you mean numbered lists (paragraphs)? And again: Would copying whole paragraphs from Test1.docx to Test2.docx be an option? Or is to put the content of multiple paragraphs from Test1.docx into one paragraph in Test2.docx the requirement?

Comment: Let say 
"1. Introduction" is present in Test1.Docx.
So, I am able to copy only "Introduction" in Test2.docx

Comment: If the "1." in "1. Introduction" would be simply text within a run, then it would be copied. Since you say, it will not be copied, I suspect, it is automatic paragraph numbering. If so, we have to copy `/word/numbering.xml` from the source document too. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Copying whole paragraphs from one `Word` docx to another will be simpler than taking all the content from one `Word` docx to a single run in a single paragraph of another. And since you stated that there are numberings in the source docx, the whole paragraphs are needed since only paragraphs can be numbered.

But to copy the numberings, the `/word/numbering.xml` must also be copied.
So if the Test1.docx looks like this:
[image]

After processing the following program:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTNumbering;

import java.util.List;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class CopyWordParagraphsDocToDoc {
 public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument docx1 = new XWPFDocument(new  FileInputStream("Test1.docx"));
  XWPFNumbering numberingDocx1 = docx1.getNumbering();
  // get paragraphListDocx1 as a List of all paragraphs from docx1
  List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphListDocx1 =  docx1.getParagraphs();

  // get the numbering.xml from docx1 to docx2
  // this is needed if some of the paragraphs from docx1 are numbered
  XWPFDocument docx2= new XWPFDocument(); 
  if (numberingDocx1 != null) {
   XWPFNumbering numberingDocx2 = docx2.createNumbering();
   try {
    Field f = numberingDocx1.getClass().getDeclaredField("ctNumbering");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    numberingDocx2.setNumbering((CTNumbering)f.get(numberingDocx1));
   } catch (NoSuchFieldException nsfex) {
   } catch (IllegalAccessException iaex) {
   }
  }

  // create a paragraph in docx2
  XWPFParagraph paragraphDocx2 = docx2.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraphDocx2.createRun();
  run.setText("This is from Test1.docx:");

  // this will copy all paragraphs from paragraphListDocx1 to docx2
  for (XWPFParagraph paragraphDocx1 : paragraphListDocx1) { 
   paragraphDocx2 = docx2.createParagraph();
   docx2.setParagraph(paragraphDocx1, docx2.getPosOfParagraph(paragraphDocx2));            
  }

  paragraphDocx2 = docx2.createParagraph();
  run = paragraphDocx2.createRun();
  run.setText("^-- this was from Test1.docx.");


  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("Test2.docx"));
  docx2.write(out); 
  docx2.close();   

  System.out.println("Test2.docx written successfully");
 }
}
```

The Test2.docx will look like this:

[image]

Note:
Tables will not be copied since we only copy paragraphs. 
Pictures will be broken since the `/word/media/*.*` is not copied.
Special stylings like "Heading 1" will not be copied since we not copy `/word/styles.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.VerticalAlign;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

public class FontStyle 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception 
   {
   //Blank Document
   XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument(); 

   //Write the Document in file system
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
   new File("fontstyle.docx"));

   //create paragraph
   XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();

   //Set Bold an Italic
   XWPFRun paragraphOneRunOne = paragraph.createRun();
   paragraphOneRunOne.setBold(true);
   paragraphOneRunOne.setItalic(true);
   paragraphOneRunOne.setText("Font Style");
   paragraphOneRunOne.addBreak();

   //Set text Position
   XWPFRun paragraphOneRunTwo = paragraph.createRun();
   paragraphOneRunTwo.setText("Font Style two");
   paragraphOneRunTwo.setTextPosition(100);

   //Set Strike through and Font Size and Subscript
   XWPFRun paragraphOneRunThree = paragraph.createRun();
   paragraphOneRunThree.setStrike(true);
   paragraphOneRunThree.setFontSize(20);
   paragraphOneRunThree.setSubscript(
   VerticalAlign.SUBSCRIPT);
   paragraphOneRunThree.setText(" Different Font Styles");

   document.write(out);
   out.close();
   System.out.println("fontstyle.docx written successully");
   }
}
```

Props to: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_word/apache_poi_word_font_style.htm

Comment: Actually, I want to read a word document and write it into another word document in the same style as it is in the first document.
Suppose, data in 1st document is :
'My name is XYZ'. and 'XYZ' is in bold.
So I want 'My name is XYZ' to be written in 2nd file with 'XYZ' in bold.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Files copy method from java. Use the below code snippet:

```
Files.copy(new File("source path location"), new File("destination path location"));
```

Hope that, it serves the purpose.